# create ER-Diagram for mongoid + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, erd

I am using Mongoid in Rails 4. Is there any gem which can generate ERD from the project.

https://github.com/huangw/mongoid-erd-gem

I checked this page but not able to understand how to use this.
Any help Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Railroady is a gem that supports mongoid.It also depends on graphviz https://github.com/preston/railroady